# Some emojis has a length of 3? (digits)

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, emoji

I am trying to implement a way of counting the number of emojis in a `NSString`. I have found a way that works with most emojis, but I am struggling with some emojis, that seems to be defined in a different way than others.

For example the [hot beverage](http://www.emojibase.com/emoji/2615/hotbeverage) icon has a unicode hex of `U+2615` (codepoint 9749), but the [zero digit](http://www.emojibase.com/emoji/0030-20e3/keycapdigitzero) has a unicode hex of `U+0030 U+20E3` (codepoint 3154147).

I am using this `NSString` category to determine the number of emojis:

```
@implementation NSString (Emojis)

- (BOOL)isEmoji
{
    const unichar high = [self characterAtIndex: 0];

    // Surrogate pair (U+1D000-1F77F)
    if (0xd800 <= high && high <= 0xdbff)
    {
        const unichar low = [self characterAtIndex: 1];
        const int codepoint = ((high - 0xd800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xdc00) + 0x10000;

        return (0x1d000 <= codepoint && codepoint <= 0x1f77f);
    }
    else // Not surrogate pair (U+2100-27BF)
    {
        return (0x2100 <= high && high <= 0x27bf);
    }
}

- (NSUInteger)numbersOfEmojis
{
    NSUInteger __block emojiCount = 0;
    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])
                             options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                          usingBlock: ^(NSString* substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL* stop) {
                              if ([substring isEmoji])
                              {
                                  emojiCount++;
                              }
                          }];

    return emojiCount;
}
@end
```

Most emojis has a length of 2 which works finde in the algorithm because of the `high` and `low` unicodes, but the digit has a length of 3 and the `high` unicode does not match the range of a surrogate pair (`0xd800 <= high && high <= 0xdbff`).

I can't find any documentation that describes the ranges for this type of emoji. Is there a way of handling this type of emojis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is called “Keycap Digit Zero Emoji” on the page cited is not an emoji at all (though it could be used in an emoji-like manner) but simply two Unicode characters, the common digit 0 (U+0030) and U+20E3 COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP, which is a combining mark.

A combining mark like U+20E3 can be used after any character to produce symbols like keycap 0, 0⃣, or keycap $, $⃣ (as you can see, these won’t work perfectly in all contexts, due to font problems).

Such a combination is two characters, for the technical meaning of “character” as an element of a coded character set. If you want to count it as one symbol, you need to define and implement the logic for this yourself. Note that there is a large number of combining marks in Unicode, and there is an infinite number of combinations of characters and combining marks (since you can use combining marks in succession).